raise ValueError("RSA key format is not supported") Convert a string into RSA Key Python
I am trying to create a RSA publickey with a text that is entered by user. I use Cryptodomex library. Although I have used PEM to create a string in PEM format, it did not work and there was an error ValueError("RSA key format is not supported").
I have tried adding more blank spaces to make the key long-enough. However, it still did not work.
from Crypto.PublicKey import RSA
from Crypto.Cipher import PKCS1_OAEP
import base64
from Crypto.IO import PEM

public_key = 'PUBPUB'
# public_key += (2048 - len(public_key)) * ' '

public_key = PEM.encode(public_key.encode(), 'PUBLIC KEY')
print(public_key)
rsa_key = RSA.import_key(public_key.encode())


RSA keys consist of an exponent and modulus. These two fields are then encoded using something like PKCS1, only then can you encode it using PEM. If you want to derive them yourself, you can call the RsaKey constructor yourself and pass your values. But ideally, you'd use PBKDF2 to derive a seed from the user input, seed a CSPRNG using that and use the RSA.generate function.

What is the meaning of public_key = 'PUBPUB'? That's obviously not a valid public key.
